# How to have multiple views for sharepoint documents?

Tags: sharepoint, list, view

I have a sharepoint with a lot of documents stored in it. I would like to have different views for these documents. One view would be by "project" to see all related project documents, another view would be "Design Documents" to view all design documents across all projects. Is there a way to do list so that there is only 1 copy of the document?

Comment: When you look at the document library in the SharePoint UI, is there a "Views" dropdown in the header above the documents? Is the last item in that dropdown "Create View"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse there is, that's what [list view's](http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:nFKJQRu-JRkJ:office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA100215771033.aspx+SharePoint+edit+list+views+site:microsoft.com&cd=7&hl=lv&ct=clnk&gl=lv) are for.

You can group, filter and sort items based on various fields.

Comment: Does everything need to be in the same folder?

Comment: SharePoint does better if everything is in the same folder. You can get the appearance of multiple folders by grouping and filtering, based on user choices. If everything is in folders, then the user cannot choose how it appears - each item will always appear in its parent folder.

Comment: Actually you can use flat view if you like (view items from all folders): http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=120